# How to fix incosistent and slow Google Cloud Storage response times?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Storage to store and retrieve some files, and my problem is that the response times I'm getting are inconsistent, and sometimes very slow.

My application is an ASP.NET Core app running in the Google Container Engine. The Container Engine cluster is in `europe-west1-c`. The Cloud Storage bucket is Multi-Regional, in the location `EU`, and it's a secure bucket (not publicly accessible). I'm using the latest version of the official `Google.Cloud.Storage.V1` SDK package to access the Cloud Storage. (I tried both `1.0.0` and the new `2.0.0-beta01`.) I'm using a singleton instance of the `StorageClient` object, which should do connection pooling under the hood.

I'm measuring and logging the time it takes to download a file from the Cloud Storage, this is the measurement I do.

```
var sw = Stopwatch.CreateNew();

await client.DownloadObjectAsync(googleCloudOptions.StorageBucketName, filepath, ms);

sw.Stop();
```

So I'm directly measuring the SDK call without any of my own application logic.

The numbers I'm getting for this measurement look like this in an average period.

```
44ms
56ms
501ms
274ms
90ms
237ms
145ms
979ms
446ms
148ms
```

You can see that the variance is already pretty large to begin with (and the response time is often really sluggish).

But occasionally I even get response times like this (the slowest I've seen was over 10 seconds).

```
172ms
4,348ms
72ms
51ms
179ms
2,508ms
2,592ms
100ms
```

Which is really bad considering that the file I'm downloading is ~2 KB in size, and my application is doing less than 1 requests per second, and I'm running my application inside the Google Cloud. I don't think that the bucket not being warmed up can be a problem, since I'm mainly downloading the same handful of files, and I'm doing at least a couple of requests every minute.

Does anyone know what can be the reason for this slowness, or how I could investigate what's going wrong?

**Update**: Following @jterrace's suggestion, I've run `gsutil perfdiag` on the production environment, and uploaded both the terminal output and the generated json report [here](https://gist.github.com/markvincze/6b652e5c2052a3fd9932b8df75d6cafe).

I also collected some more measurements, here you can see the statistics for the last 7 days.

[image: Diagram showing statistics about Cloud Storage download times.]

So you can see that slow requests don't happen super-often, but over half a second response time is not rare, and we even have a handful of requests over 5 seconds every day.

What I'd like to figure out is whether we're doing something wrong, or this is expected with Cloud Storage and we have to be prepared to be able to handle these slow responses on our side.

Comment: Where is your application running? On GCE or on your own server? Can you reproduce the results with [gsutil perfdiag](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/perfdiag) ?

Comment: My app is running in GCE in `europe-west1-c`. I haven't tried `gsutil perfdiag`, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Well, I tried `gsutil perfdiag`, the download times varied between 150ms-500ms, and I didn't see any super-slow times.
But I'm not sure if this is even representative, since I was doing this from my machine, while my actual application runs in GCE, so that should be even faster (?).

Comment: I would definitely test it out on GCE. Depending on where your local machine is and its connection, results could vary widely.

Comment: Hey @jterrace, it took some time for me to be able to run the benchmark on production, I updated the post now with the results, and with some additional statistics.

Comment: Er, AFAIK Google make no guarantees about latency in their cloud systems. It's not a real time system. Nor is anyone else's. It's not going to behave like a locally attached SSD...

Comment: how do you configure the timeout for Google Cloud Storage in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the same issue with GCS. The only answer we got (from GCS support) is to use exponential backoff. 
First request should be with 200ms timeout, next try 400ms and so on.

Comment: I was always using exponential backoff for reliability, but never realized it can be used for latency :)

Comment: Since then we also got an official answer from GCloud support, we're not doing anything wrong, it's expected to sometimes get slow response times, and simply our application has to be prepared to deal with this (preload this files and cache them, etc.). If I can't find anything else in some time, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem I've seen in GCE is that due to gcloud clients having a heavy DNS dependency, that bursts of traffic are being throttled by DNS queries, not the actual clients (storage or otherwise). I highly recommend you adding etcd or some other DNS cache to your container. Any real amount of traffic in GCE will choke otherwise.